# How can I use Flex in JSP project

Tags: java, apache-flex, jakarta-ee

How can I use flex in my Java EE project and what new can I do with Flex as I'm unable to run flex application in Netbeans after installing Plugin and add SDK as well

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What did you try? What errors did you get? Did you first try to solve those errors and got blocked at some point? For example, you can try duplicating this tutorial: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FlexApplicationsWithNetBeans and if you have a specific error while doing it, you can post details on it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the following tutorial and duplicate its exercises if you are completely beginner: http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/Flex/Flex_Chapter20.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Flex ultimately gets compiled to a SWF file. If you have seen some Flash animation on a webpage, click view source, thats how it would look like. JSP will generate the html with the SWF file embedded in it. There are free IDEs for flex like [flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).
You can also develop flex apps using plain text editor and flex sdk just like java.